# Grails Criteria Projection - No signature of method projections() is applicable for argument types

Tags: grails

As per Grails documentation

> Grails also lets you write your domain model in Java or reuse an existing one that already has Hibernate mapping files. Simply place the mapping files into grails-app/conf/hibernate and either put the Java files in src/java or the classes in the project's lib directory if the domain model is packaged as a JAR. You still need the hibernate.cfg.xml though!

So This is exactley what i did.

I have used java domain model and hibernate.cfg.xml file for mapping. I also use
{DomainName}Constraints.groovy for adding Grails constraints. I also used to add functions to {DomainName}Constraints. For example, below is the content of my EmployeeConstraints.groovy

```
Employee.metaClass.static.findByDepartment = {depCode ->
    createCriteria().list {
        department{ 
            inList ('code', depCode) 
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works fine. But, when i add projection to it(code below), just to get the employee code.

```
Employee.metaClass.static.findByDepartment = {depCode ->
    createCriteria().list {
        projections { property('empCode', 'empCode') }
        department { inList ('code', depCode) }

    }

}
```

I get the below error..

" No signature of method: com.package.script142113.projections() is applicable for argument types.. "

Can someone point me to whats wrong with the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `property` projection is used to return a subset of an object's properties. For example, to return just the `foo` and `bar` properties use:

```
projections { 
    property('foo')
    property('bar')
}
```

You're getting an error because you've called the `property` method with 2 arguments instead of one.

By the way, I see another potential with your code. Grails will automatically create a dynamic finder `findByDepartment` that has the same name as the method your trying to add via the meta-class. I have no idea which one will take precendence, but I would suggest you avoid this potential problem and simplify your code, by adding this query using Grails' [named query](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) support, and call it something like `getByDepartment` so that the name doesn't class with a dynamic finder.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Dónal should be the correct one, but I found a strange behavior with grails 3.1. I got the same message using this call:

```
Announcement.createCriteria().list {
    projections {
        property('id')
        property('title')
    }
} .collect { [id: it['id'], title: it['title']] } // it['id'] not found
```

I fixed it by removing projections closure:

```
Announcement.createCriteria().list {
    property('id')
    property('title')
} .collect { [id: it['id'], title: it['title']] } // got the it['id']
```

Hope this help.